# Photorec filled ssd

Tags: 16.04, ssd, storage

Ubuntu 16.04.
After finding my TB drive empty, I used Photorec to copy deleted files to my 120 GB SSD. I didn't realize how much I had deleted before and it filled my SSD entirely up. I deleted the recovery files so I could instead do the recovery on a different one, yet the disk space was still totally taken up in Disks. I assumed it was a glitch, so I copied my entire home folder onto the TB drive (the lost data wasn't extremely important anyways), `rm`'d /home/ and copied it back in from the bigger drive. When I checked empty space, it was still showing only 17 MB free. How to fix my drive?

Answer (score 0):

Try to repair the file system(s). Use linux tools to repair linux file systems and Windows tools to repair Windows file systems.

I guess your root partition has an ext4 file system.

- Boot from another drive, for example a USB boot/install drive with Ubuntu, 'Try Ubuntu'
- Unmount the root partition

  ```
  sudo umount /dev/sdxy
  ```

where x is the drive letter (maybe a) and y is the partition number (maybe 1)
so maybe '/dev/sda1'.

- Run the following command in a terminal window

  ```
  sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdxy
  ```
- Do the same for the home partition if you have one.

See this link for more details (the instructions are valid for internal drives too)

[Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986)